# How to add appendix to publish artifacts?

Tags: java, gradle, maven-publish

I need add appendix to publish artifacts. For build task it is easy. But it doesn't work when I try publish artifacts via maven-publish plugin. Appendix are not added.

```
plugins {
    id 'maven-publish'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '1.5.19.RELEASE'
    id 'org.asciidoctor.convert' version '1.5.3'
}

def env = 'something'

jar {
    enabled = true
    appendix env
}

sourceJar {
    appendix env
}


apiDocZip {
    appendix env
}
```

In result I get follow artifacts:

```
artifact-something-0.0.0.jar
artifact-something-0.0.0-sources.jar
artifact-something-0.0.0-apidoc.zip
```

But when I use task publishToMavenLocal, then I get follow:

```
artifact-0.0.0.jar
artifact-0.0.0.pom
artifact-0.0.0-sources.jar
artifact-0.0.0-apidoc.zip
```

How can you see appendix was not added. Is there any solution to add appendix to publish artifacts?